# In Anno 1404, how do I take over trade buildings without them disappearing?

Tags: anno-1404

Situation: Whenever I invade another player's island, I set up like 5-6 military camps around the trade buildings to capture them. After waiting a loooong time, when the timer hits 0 and the ownership is meant to be given to me, they instead collapse and disappear. WTF? How do I stop this and get to keep the buildings? It's making taking over islands extreeemely slow since the NPC just builds a new warehouse straight after.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the enemies are **razing the building** in order to keep you from taking it over. 
I'm not sure if the likelihood of this increases with the difficulty you're playing on, but in case it does, you may want to try lowering the difficulty.

In order to increase the speed of takeover, I wouldn't rely on trade building capture being your *only* method. Here are a few steps you can take to speed it up.

- If you have enough resources, **upgrade your Castle to a Warehouse**. If you're having trouble taking control of the island, then establishing a Warehouse will benefit you greatly, as you can store your goods and start establishing markets with those goods. In addition, you should **stock your strong box** with items that will increase your military's effectiveness.
- **Build an Oriental Forts** and **Assassin's Camps** so you can produce units which will have bonuses for capturing.
- Use trebuchets and cannons to **make holes in walls** so your land units can move around easier.
- If you're playing on Easy or Medium, you can **tear down enemy buildings in your influence area** to provide yourself with more materials.
- **Blockade** enemy warehouses/castles.
- If you're not concerned about having to rebuild homes, then **set it all on fire**. Take out the fire stations, then use trebuchets/cannons to wreak havoc.

[Source](http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/Combat#Taking_over_market_buildings_and_marketplaces)

Comment: I don't think it is the enemy razing buildings, because these buildings are all heavily within my influence area and they all disappear on the very last second. When an enemy invades my area I can't destroy my own buildings if they are in their influence area. I already knew of all the other suggestions you had, I have read the anno wiki quite religiously (lol) so I am really at a loss to understand why conquering takes so long.

Comment: And I should note, I'm playing on Easy/Medium and my army is usually massively overpowering my opponent's.